# typescript type of class that has to be initialized

Tags: typescript, oop

```
let circle: Circle;
```

This line says that `circle` is an instance of `Circle`. There is a case when I have a list of factories, they have not been initialized (list of classes). I have to process their static properties. What type should I use for this?

I receive such error:

```
 error TS2576: Property 'version' is a static member of type 'MigrationContainerBase'
```

Here's the code where I receive the error:

```
@injectable()
export class MigrationManagerContainer implements IMigrationManagerContainer {

    @inject(ContainerType.CurrentVersion)
    private currentVersionContainer: ICurrentVersionContainer;

    @multiInject(ContainerType.Migration)
    private migrations: MigrationContainerBase[];

    public getMigrations() {
        return Promise.resolve(this.migrations.sort((a, b) => {
            compareVersions(a['version'], b['version'])
        }));
    }
    ....
 }

@migration('0.0.2')
class _0_0_2_Migration extends MigrationContainerBase {
    up() {
        project.state = 'State->0.0.2'
    }

    down() {
        project.state = 'State->0.0.1'
    }
}

@migration('0.0.3')
class _0_0_3_Migration extends MigrationContainerBase {
    up() {
        project.state = 'State->0.0.3'
    }

    down() {
        project.state = 'State->0.0.2'
    }
}

@migration('0.0.1')
class _0_0_1_Migration extends MigrationContainerBase {
    up() {
        project.state = 'State->0.0.1'
    }

    down() {
        project.state = 'State->0.0.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that's giving you that error as well as the definition of `MigrationContainerBase`?

Comment: This solves the error compareVersions(a['version'], b['version'])  But I want to understand how to process type reflection typed.

Comment: It's really hard to help out or even understand what you want without the code for the classes.

Comment: I have migrations and migration manager. In the manager I modify m igration classes. https://gist.github.com/vlikin/77123d50effc6ea0ef89fc087fcbfa5a You see that I work with classes not with instances of classes.

Comment: I do not need solve the error. I need to get new knowledge. Please read the title. typescript type of class that has to be initialized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how to implement this with the `@migration` and `@multiInject` decorators since you haven't provided them. But since you are specifically asking about how typing in such a scenario, I hope this will shed enough light on it to allow you to come up with your own implementation.

You're correct. When you declare something like

```
const circle: Circle;
```

You are saying the variable named `circle` contains an *instance of* the type `Circle`. The important distinction here is that the left-hand side of the `:` refers to "*value space*" and the right-hand refers to "*type space*"<sup>1</sup>. In TypeScript, classes in a way occupy both type space and value space because their constructor functions are values. If you want to refer to the type that the value-space name `Circle` represents, you can use the `typeof` keyword (this is different from the [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) from JavaScript).

```
const circleClass: typeof Circle = Circle;
const circle = new circleClass(); // inferred type: Circle
```

Alternatively, you can describe static properties of the class or its class constructor, for example:

```
const circleClass: { new(): Circle } = Circle;
const circle = new circleClass(); // inferred type: Circle
```

This by itself may not be helpful in your case. With an abstract class, you generally intend that every subclass must provide its own members that satisfy some constraint, but this cannot be done with static members. To get around this, you're probably better off creating a separate interface for the static description, for example:

```
interface IMigrationContainer {
    new(): MigrationContainerBase
    version: string;
    // ... any other static members declared here
}
abstract class MigrationContainerBase {
    abstract up(): void;
    abstract down(): void;
    // any other abstract instance members here
}
```

And use the interface in your migration container class:

```
private migrations: IMigrationContainer[];

public getMigrations() {
    return Promise.resolve(this.migrations.sort((a, b) => {
        return compareVersions(a['version'], b['version']);
    }));
}
```

Then your migrations classes should look something like this (notice that I don't use `implements IMigrationContainer`):

```
class _0_0_1_Migration extends MigrationContainerBase {
    static version: string = "0.0.1";
    up() {}
    down() {}
}
```

<sub>1. "*type space*" and "*value space*" are not part of any official terminology. It's just what I call these concepts because it helps me to better understand what's going on inside the TypeScript compiler.</sub>